# Cannot read property 'URI' of undefined, Ionic2

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'URI' of undefined"

I got this error whenever I try to use native screenshot method in Ionic2.

My code:

```
this.screenshot.URI(80).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);
}, (err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

This is Ionic2 screenshot documentation: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screenshot/

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "4.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "4.0.0",
"@angular/core": "4.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "4.0.0",
"@angular/http": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "4.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.0.0",
"@ionic-native/camera": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.6.1",
"@ionic-native/file": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/file-path": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic-native/screenshot": "^3.6.1",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/transfer": "^3.6.0",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
"crypto-js": "3.1.9-1",
"fast-sha256": "1.0.0",
"ionic-angular": "3.0.1",
"ionic-native": "^3.5.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.1.1",
"sha256": "0.2.0",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"ts-md5": "1.2.0",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

Comment: in title "TypeError: Cannot read property 'URI' of undefined"

Comment: you have added as provider right? can you show package.json?

Comment: yes, it is added as provider, package added in first post

Comment: try calling within `this.platform.ready().then(()=>{})`..

Comment: still got same error :(

Comment: not sure if this will help but you could try to match all your ionic-native versions https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/blob/master/package.json from the starte app link..

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Did you found any solution yet?